# How to check if a user is logged on in mediawiki in a different app?

Tags: python, authentication, mediawiki

Here is the situation:

I have a Mediawiki installation, and a few additional server-side scripts that require more resources and were already written in a different language (python). The python code will be very loosely coupled with the Mediawiki code (only called by clicking on a link here or there)

What I would like is that when a GET or POST command is sent to the server to execute a python script, I would like to check to see if a user is already logged in to Mediawiki. If not, I would like to just redirect them to the Mediawiki login page.
Any ideas?

There are several articles on integrating Mediawiki with other PHP frameworks like Drupal and forum software, but that is more than I need.

```
What is the best way to do this?
-check for cookies somehow (is this secure?)
-does the Mediawiki database keep track of who is logged in?
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a question. Are your MediaWiki installation and your Python scripts exposed under the same port, protocol and domain? If not, you will not be able to check any visitor session. The cookies are not shared between different websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query_-_Meta#userinfo_.2F_ui) to get the userinfo and parse that in XML.

Comment: Ok, I see this, but the problem is that the API takes the user name as an argument. How could I prevent someone from spoofing the name? Basically, I'm assuming that I need to do 2 things:
1) Find out which user is attempting to use the service
2) Find out if this user has legitimately logged on this session

Comment: I think you're reading the API response as the query to construct. I just tried on my installation, and getting the page '/api.php?action=query&meta=userinfo&uiprop=rights|hasmsg' returns information about my logged-in session. If you just want to know if the user is logged in, just get the meta=userinfo alone (api.php?action=query&meta=userinfo). If the user is not logged in to an appropriate user, the returned userinfo tag will have the 'anon' attribute. All you need to do is essentially forward the session, cookies and all, to the API as if it's the user querying.

Answer (score 2):

mediawiki check if logged in:

```
<?php
global $wgUser;
require_once('StubObject.php');
if( StubObject::isRealObject( $wgUser ) &&  $wgUser->isLoggedIn())
{

// code or HTML

}
?>
```

I have also seen the following for skins (i.e. MonoBook.php), but I have not tested:

```
if(!$this->data['loggedin']) {

}
```

Warning: Make sure you test!  There may be ways for people to get around the above tests... giving them access to content.  I use it to simply hide the menu. If someone got around the above method I don't mind since they only see the menu.

Comment: This answer was useful to me but actually it is not useful to the person that asked a Python solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on Jon's post due to lack of privileges, so I'm posting a new answer to elaborate on his about using MediaWiki API and passing cookies. Hopefully this helps someone.

You can use PHP's cURL library to pass the session cookie value as a cookie to the api.php page in your wiki (you need to create a complete URL for cURL to fetch the page). The session cookie name is either the value of $wgSessionCookie (which is set to false by default and not used) or `$wgCookiePrefix . '_session'` ($wgCookiePrefix is set to false by default and defaults to the database name). So based on the setup you have, use the appropriate value.

I use `api.php?action=query&format=xml&meta=userinfo` and then look for the user id that is returned by the wiki (Note [format=xml](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aData_formats#Output)). Id of 0 means that the user is anonymous.

Here is the complete code for the function that I use (I realize that I don't check for some possible error conditions). You will probably have to change the $session_cookie value

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
  $session_cookie = 'wikidb_session';
  if(!isset($_COOKIE[$session_cookie]))
  {
    return false;
  }

  $url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))?'https://':'http://') .
         $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .
         (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80)?':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']:'') .
         '/wiki/api.php?action=query&format=xml&meta=userinfo';

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $session_cookie . '=' . $_COOKIE[$session_cookie]);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  $ret = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  return preg_match('/id="(\d+)"/',$ret,$id) && $id[1];
}
```

Note: If you only check whether anon="" or id="0" is returned by the api.php call, in the event that the call returns something unexpected or api.php is not at the URL, the function will report user as logged in, so it's better to check the id that is returned.

Comment: In a PHP script, you'll probably find `format=php` much easier to parse reliably.  (Just pass it through `unserialize()`.)

Comment: @Aurimas I'm trying to run this code but it seems the curl_setopt commands are taking forever and my browser isn't loading. I'm building a chrome extension and I want to track if the user is already logged in to the mediawiki site. If not, I want to prompt the user to login. Is there anything else I would need to include besides this code?

Comment: @zock I can't comment on whether this still works or not, since I haven't used it in a long time and I don't have the means to test it now, but I'm not really following what the PHP curl_setopt command would have to do with a Chrome extension that's written in JavaScript.

Comment: @Aurimas thanks for your reply. I want to pass the cookie and session information from mediawiki to the extension. I wanted to use the code above to retrieve the cookie session information.

Answer (score 0):

> All you need to do is essentially forward the session, cookies and all, to the API as if it's the user querying.

How would one go about doing that? I can access the API directly and see my login info, but if I access it via PHP, it shows me as not being logged in (anonymous user id "0"). How do I forward the session, cookies, etc. to the API via PHP to show the user's info?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Extension:Third party session verification](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Third_party_session_verification) to verify that a user is logged in without forwarding their session to your backend service.