# In-python MediaWiki authentication from cookies

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, openid, mediawiki

What would be **easiest** way to use MediaWiki cookies in some Python CGI scripts (on the same domain, ofc) for authentication (including MW's OpenID, especially)?

Access from python to MediaWiki database is possible, too.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170990/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-on-in-mediawiki-in-a-different-app

Comment: Thanks, that's quite relevant.

Comment: Which problem do you want to solve with your script?

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to and modify the SQL-database without HTTP and cookies using the [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) module, but this is often the wrong solution to do MediaWiki maintenance. Though read-only-access should not be a problem.

The best way to access MediaWiki with a script is to use the [api.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page).

The best known Python based MediaWiki-API-bot is the [Pywikibot](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) (former [Pywikipediabot](http://pywikipediabot.sourceforge.net/)).

The easiest way to save cookies in Python might be to use the [http.cookiejar](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.cookiejar.html) module.
Its documentation contains some simple examples.

I extracted functional example code out of my own MediaWiki-bot:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import http.cookiejar
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json

s_login_name = 'example'
s_login_password = 'secret'

s_api_url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
s_user_agent = 'StackOverflowExample/0.0.1.2012.09.26.1'

def api_request(d_post_params):
    d_post_params['format'] = 'json'
    r_post_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(d_post_params).encode('utf-8')
    o_url_request = urllib.request.Request(s_api_url, r_post_params)
    o_url_request.add_header('User-Agent', s_user_agent)
    o_http_response = o_url_opener.open(o_url_request)
    s_reply = o_http_response.read().decode('utf-8')
    d_reply = json.loads(s_reply)
    return (o_http_response.code, d_reply)

o_cookie_jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
o_http_cookie_processor = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(o_cookie_jar)
o_url_opener = urllib.request.build_opener(o_http_cookie_processor)

d_post_params = {'action': 'login', 'lgname': s_login_name}
i_code, d_reply = api_request(d_post_params)
print('http code: %d' % (i_code))
print('api reply: %s' % (d_reply))

s_login_token = d_reply['login']['token']

d_post_params = {
    'action': 'login',
    'lgname': s_login_name,
    'lgpassword': s_login_password,
    'lgtoken':s_login_token
}
i_code, d_reply = api_request(d_post_params)
print('http code: %d' % (i_code))
print('api reply: %s' % (d_reply))
```

Classes, error handling and sub-functions have been removed to increase readability.

The cookies saved in o_url_opener can also be used for requests to [index.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_index.php).

You could also login via index.php (fake a browser request) but this would include parsing of HTML-output.

---

Variable name legend:

```
# Unicode string
s_* = 'a'
# Bytes (raw string)
r_* = b'a'
# Dictionary
d_* = {'a':1}
# Integer number
i_* = 4711
# Other objects
o_* = SomeClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to use Cookies with mediawiki is as follows:

```
from cookielib import CookieJar
import urllib2
import urllib
import json

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
```

Now, requests can be made using opener.  For example:

```
login_data = {
'action': 'login',
'lgname': 'Example',
'lgpassword': 'Foobar',
'format': 'json'
}
data = urllib.urlencode(login_data)
request = opener.open('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',data)
content = json.load(request)
login_data['token'] = content['login']['token']
data_2 = urllib.urlencode(login_data)
request_2 = opener.open('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',data_2)
content_2 = json.load(request_2)
print content_2['login']['result']
```

In the example above, if the Cookiejar was not created, the  login wouldn't fully work, asking for another token.  Though, it'd be recommended to use a mediawiki wrapper already created such as [pywikipedia](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikipediabot), [mwhair](https://github.com/hairr/mwhair), [pytybot](https://github.com/ty-a/pytybot), [simplemediawiki](https://github.com/ianweller/python-simplemediawiki) or [wikitools](http://code.google.com/p/python-wikitools/), with hundreds of other mediawiki wrappers in python.